# How to check either email address exist or not using android?

Tags: java, android, smtp

**I want to register email in  application from the form. I want to check that either email address exist or not. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.**

Comment: This question shows very poor research effort. A simple google search can answer your query. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Send them an e-mail with a code, demand they enter the code.

Comment: this can be a comment

Comment: I think this is a better answer because you cannot validate an email id on your own. Most apps use this mechanism.

Comment: You can never make sure an e-mail actually exists by look ups. E-mail service is not reliable. No error doesn't mean the e-mail got there.

Answer (score 0):

Validity of email address can be verified only if you have a mail server for which you are authorized to check the email validity or if you own a mail server with full rights.
The only way to check email existence validity is to send an automated mail and request the user to get back the code sent in the mail.

Comment: You can not check other people's servers just because you have one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [EMAIL_ADDRESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#EMAIL_ADDRESS) regex to validate the input to check that it is a valid email address. Beyond validating that the input matches a valid email address format I'm not sure you can actually validate that the email address is in-fact valid unless you're going to implement some mechanism to have the user confirm their address (by sending them an email for example).